# How can I use a static library's protocol in my project?

Tags: xcode, swift5

I had created a static library for my project. I'm able to add the library into the project and is able to use the classes from the library.

My problem is, i couldn't use the protocol from my library, when i include it in my project's class like this

```
class MainViewController: myProtocol {
    //... my code 
}
```

it show me "Use of undeclared type 'myProtocol'", creating a new protocol at my project is not an option in my case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `import`-ed your library, then you didn’t make it `public`. Both are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check, library is displaying under "build phases -> link binary with libraries". If not you're doing something wrong while copying. Otherwise there are two possibilities, either you haven't imported the Library in your class or there is wrong implementation of access modifier in your library.